# rsync to restore backup not working

Tags: rsync, restore

I'm trying to use RSYNC to restore a backup. I am trying to restore all files by running the same command that the script runs to backup but with the destination and target switched around.

```
rsync -rltpqz --delete username@remotehost.com:dir /users/home/username/
```

However I get this error...

```
/users/home/username/: is a directory
```

Comment: Have you tried using the full directory path on the remote host?

Comment: Use `-v` (--verbose) instead of `-q` (--quiet) to see what it say.

Comment: sent 6699 bytes  received 7261735 bytes  73791.21 bytes/sec
total size is 2544027491  speedup is 350.01
./restore.sh: line 24: /users/home/username/: is a directory

Comment: Take out the --delete, you don't want to clobber any files not in the backup.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remain cognizant of the directory structures that you're working with. Rsync is not terribly consistent in how this is handled. Been bit a few times by this myself.

If you were backing up the directory named "username" to remotehost's /dir/ directory, you're going to want that directory with the slash from remotehost to go to /users/home on the local server.

rsync -avP username@remotehost.com:dir/username /users/home/